# define url as variable and use inside \href

Tags: macros, url

I am creating a script in python that automatically creates a a pdf using LaTeX. To make the automation easier I define variables in a file called Variables.tex which I load using

```
\input{variables}
```

This works fine usually, however now I want to create a variable with a web address inside. The file looks something like this:

```
\def \MOParameters{A, B, C}
\def \MOTitle{Measurements at location X}
\def \MORawDataURL{https://location/to/the/file}
\def \MOCountry{Countryname}
```

I then use these variables (it works fine without the variable with the web-address) like such:

```
Parameters: & \MOParameters{}\\
Link to:    & \href{\MORawDataURL}{raw data}\\
```

This however gives an error (undefined control sequence), does anybody know why?

Full document (left out comments and package loading and some simple stuff)
test.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{report}
\input{Variables}

\begin{document}
     \begin{adjustwidth}{0cm}{0cm}
     \tableofcontents %Table of contents
    \pagestyle{plain} 
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \chapter{Data information}
        \section{Meta data}
            \begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{7cm}}
                Title:              & \MOTitle{}\\
                Source:             & \MOSource{}\\
                Parameters:         & \MOParameters{}\\
                Link to:            & \href{\MORawDataURL}{raw data}\\
            \end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Variables.tex:

```
\def \MOParameters{A, B, C}
\def \MOTitle{Measurements at location x}
\def \MORawDataURL{https://localhost-108/subdir/Data/CT 2015.011/Pars}
\def \MOSource{Data}
```

Comment: Where is `\MOParameters` defined? That's the undefined macro the compilation complains about. The rest works, if it is put in a compilable document, which is your task, actually ;-)

Comment: It is also defined in the Variables.tex file, I just omitted it too keep the code short (and because it all works fine if I don't have the links). Editted the code for clarity.

Comment: No, give a document, not just fragments here ...

Comment: @Yorian This post is your friend and guide here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: you should put `\usepackage{hyperref}` below your documentclass.

Comment: I added a fuller version of the document that should help you understand it better

Comment: @Yorian: Where is `\usepackage{hyperref}` in your document? You need that package for `\href`

Comment: @Marijn That solved it, man that was a stupid mistake I made..

Comment: @Christian: Apologies you were right, should have given the full example..

Comment: @Yorian: That's precisely the point of providing documents and not fragments. Marijn spotted from your full code that `hyperref` was missing; no document means basically guessing around

Comment: This is a classic example of why providing a complete [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) is almost always so useful. The problem would've been detected instantly.

Comment: @Yorian you have learned about MWE's, that means you have succesfully completed the initiation ritual on this website :) Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Marijn: Providing an answer?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer as requested.

Comment: Be aware that some input in an url (e.g. # and %) will need special care.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For using `\href` you need to load the `hyperref` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\def \MOParameters{A, B, C}
\def \MOTitle{Measurements at location X}
\def \MORawDataURL{https://location/to/the/file}
\def \MOCountry{Countryname}

Parameters: \MOParameters{}

Link to:    \href{\MORawDataURL}{raw data}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Well done ........... spotting the error before I could :D